# Angular 4 Listening for progress on FireFox after AOT not work

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to show progress bar while file is download.
I'm using angular 4 with HttpClient.

**WITHOUT AOT**
I succeed to display progress bar on both chrome and Firefox.

**USING AOT**
I succeed to display progress bar only with chrome but not in Firefox.

**My code**

```
downloadFile(fileName) {

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'});

  const req = new HttpRequest('GET', 'some-url', {
    reportProgress: true,
    headers: headers,
    responseType: 'blob'
  });

 this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.DownloadProgress) {
      this.progressPercentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      const data = new Blob([event.body]);
      FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName);
    }
  },
  this.onDownloadError.bind(this)); };
```